# Control.Invoke delegates in CF 3.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, thread-safety

It seems like everybody have noticed CF is unable to Control.Invoke delegates other than EventHandler type. I found few ways to workaround the problem and catch the arguments trough tricky events and properties, but it works just for certain objects/primitives.

The problem is when I try to send a Control, the program throws an exception at execution time: "Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread" no matters that I checked Control.IsInvokeRequired and tracked by handler trough the Invoke method...what hell, there is the snipet:

```
    static class Program
{
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.modifier = new CModifier(ref frm);
        Application.Run(frm);
    }
 }

class CModifier
{
    internal event EventHandler Modify;

    internal CModifier(ref Form1 _frm)
    { frm = _frm; }

    private Form1 frm;

    internal void Start()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestMe));
        t.Start();
    }
    private void TestMe()
    {
        frm._current = new Label() { Text = "Try Me" };
        Modify(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal CModifier modifier;
    internal Control _current;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        modifier.Modify += new EventHandler(modifier_Modify);
        modifier.Start();
    }

    void modifier_Modify(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(modifier_Modify));
        }
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(_current);
    }

}
```

I tried to do in almost every way possible and I always get the same result.

What am I doing wrong? ----> there is a "return;" lost after Invoke.

Anyway, te actual error at my app (above is just an example) is in this procedure:

```
        internal void ManageControls(RSSDecisionMaking.InterfaceBehaviour _behaviour, Control _control)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((Action)delegate { ManageControls(_behaviour, _control); });
            return;
        }
        switch (_behaviour)
        {
            case RSSDecisionMaking.InterfaceBehaviour.Display:
                this.pnDisplayContainer.Controls.Clear();
                this.pnDisplayContainer.Controls.Add(_control);
                break;
            case RSSDecisionMaking.InterfaceBehaviour.Command:
                this.pnDisplayContainer.Controls.Clear();
                this.pnDisplayContainer.Controls.Add(_control);
                this.pnDisplayContainer.Controls[0].Focus();
                break;
        }
    }
```

The main difference is in the Invoke stuff, I'm sending a Control from another thread.

Could tell me what the difference it makes? Why this does not work?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is simple.  Your `modifier_Modify` call calls Invoke properly, but then it doesn't exit, it continues down and calls `Controls.Add` in the thread context right after the `if` block (in fact `Controls.Add` would get called twice if the Exception didn't happen).  Insert a `return` right after the `this.Invoke` call, inside the `if` block.